# Compare two rows in a one2many table in OpenERP6.1

Tags: python, odoo

How can we compare two rows in a oneTomany table in OpenERP6.1?

I have a main table, say 'XX' and i have a oneTomany table, say 'YY' corresponding to
that table.

Now, i have three columns in the 'YY' table.Every time i create records into
this table, i want to check if the values in the three columns are identical.

i.e if i click the create button and entered the first row with values
'happy','new','year',

the next time when you enter the same values, you should be prompted with
a message that these values should not be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use at least one of two methods:
1. use _sql_constraint with unique on your columns, like in

```
   _sql_constraints = [
    ('number_uniq', 'unique(number, company_id, journal_id, type)', 'Invoice Number must be unique per Company!'),
]
```

from account.invoice object, or

override create/write methods for yy object and write a onchange function for your fields.

Comment: Many Thanks user7888049..when we override the create/write methods,the messsage will be shown only after the saving the record in main table..My requirement is to show the message after creating a row in the YY object..Now, for the onchange function to work,we need atleast one row to be saved in the YY object..but even though we see a row created in the YY object..it will not be physically saved in the DB table unless the SAVE button of the main object is being clicked.....could you please suggest a solution for this??

Comment: Write onchange for each of the fields hapy, new, year. In every onchange fields you search in the database for the value of other two fields from current record (value from view) in the record one2many for current xx and if found current value for the edited field in a record, raise error. Use also context for that. A complex onchange can be found in sale.order.line on product_id field. For context sample please look in sale.view_order_form.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use `_constraint`? You will only get warning when you are saving the record.